# Setuid-bit and apt-get strange behavior

Tags: c, apt-get, setuid

I have a strange behavior at my raspberry pi.

I wrote a small C-Program to update the RPi. 
It just calls via system() "apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade && apt-get upgrade && rpi-update && reboot"

With the setuid-bit the program will be running as root.

Why a c program ? Because the setuid-bit don't works with bash scripts.

As a super user there is no problem.

If I run the program as an normal user I got this error after "apt-get update" (sorry for the german version):

```
 E: Unable to write to /var/cache/apt/               
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

The setuid-bit is set and the owner of the executable is root. 
So why I have another behavior ?

Here is the code:

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
        int status = 0;

        if (status == 0) {
                status = system("apt-get -y update");        }

        if (status == 0) {
                status = system("apt-get -y dist-upgrade");
}
        if (status == 0) {
                status = system("apt-get -y upgrade");
        }

        if (status == 0) {
                status = system("rpi-update");
        }

        if (status == 0) {
                status = system("reboot");
        }
        return status;
}
```

Makefile:

```
CC=gcc
TARGET=update-system
PREFIX=/usr/bin

all: main.o
        ${CC} -o ${TARGET} main.c
        make clean

main.o: main.c
        ${CC} -c main.c

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm ./*.o 
install:
        chown root ${TARGET} 
        chgrp root ${TARGET} 
        chmod +s ${TARGET}
        mv ${TARGET} ${PREFIX}
```

Comment: Maybe you should fist check if your package manager not already running. Your user has privileges ? Any way you should use sudo there.

Comment: But why i have to use sudo if the program runs with root privileges (from the setuid-bit) ? I thought it's the same as if running as root itself ?

Comment: Never use root, use sudo instead for security reasons.

Comment: So there is a difference running something as root or with sudo ?

Comment: @PeterC.Glade There's a huge difference.  The code you posted can be leveraged to allow any user who calls it to obtain full root access.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#Security for a start.

Comment: @PeterC.Glade when you get yourself in trouble because of that, well you will remember me. Any way system() is also one thing which i never use it :). If you really need system() you should be 100% sure that you don't need bash instead of C for such things. Hope you understand my point.

Comment: How to get a root shell using this example:  `ln -s /bin/bash ~/bin/rpi-update; PATH=~/bin:$PATH; update-system`  As @Michi posted, this is what `sudo` is for.

Comment: I thought of the useage from passwd. There is a setuid-bit too. So what makes passwd secure ?

Comment: `passwd` has very specific usage and does not execute any external program.

Comment: Ok, i think i have to get more informations about root access and sudo ;) thanks a lot for your help ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your program runs, the effective user ID is root, but the real user ID is yourself.  Then when you call `system`, the real and effective user IDs get inherited by `apt-get`.

It seems that `apt-get` looks at the real user ID when checking permissions.  So you need to set the real user ID to root at the beginning of `main`:

```
setuid(0);
```

That being said, using `sudo` is more secure that running a setuid-root program, since you can control who has the privileges to do so.

Comment: There is no reason to call root for that. For to many security reasons.

Comment: **That being said, using sudo is more secure** You got +1 for that :)

Answer (score 0):

You need sudo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    int status = 0;

    if (status == 0) {
        status = system("sudo apt-get -y update");        }

    if (status == 0) {
        status = system("sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade");
    }

    if (status == 0) {
        status = system("sudo apt-get -y upgrade");
    }

    if (status == 0) {
        status = system("sudo rpi-update");
    }

    if (status == 0) {
        status = system("sudo reboot");
    }
    return status;
}
```

Just make sure that your **user** has root privileges.

Comment: The setuid bit sets the euid of the process.  The process just needs to call `setuid()`. `sudo` is unecessary.  See @dbush's answer.

Comment: Yes that's true, but i never recommend tu use root user for any reason, at least if you know that are you doing.

Comment: Agreed.  My comment was meant only in the context of obtaining full root access from a setuid-binary, not how insecure the manner used to get that access would be.  Because the example provides multiple opportunities for mischief.